# unable to get data from one jQuery file to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on the development of a website with login, profile view functionality. So I was working with the login and getting to the profile part. 
I deployed the login part correctly. I get back an array of data to fill in the profile.html page. However, when I go to profile.html page using location.href, I seem to lost that data as login.js has been reloaded. 
I have tried with keeping all the jQuery code (login and profile) inside login.js however, it does not work as when I hit the location.href function, whole JS file reloaded. Everyone of my scenario/solution kind of stopped whenever I hit that location.href function. 
I checked the validity of the data using console.log as well as printing it out in the screen in a div (in the login page).

My question is how to load the profile.html page without losing my data in the array? 
I am providing the code for login.js although I dont think that would be necessary.

```
function getData()
{
    $.ajax(
       {
           url:"http://localhost/dataFetch.php",
           dataType:"json",
           type:"GET",
           success: function(suc)
           {
               mainArray = suc;
               location.href="temp.html";
               length = mainArray["desc"].length;
           },
           error: function(err)
           {
               alert("connection to server has be interrupted");
               console.log(err);
           }
       });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^ or `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `sessionStorage` to store a variable if logged in:

`sessionStorage.setItem("loggedInStatus", "In");`

then upon page load you could use an if statement and if it returns true use the `$.getScript()` method:

```
var variable = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedInStatus");
if (variable != null) {
    $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
      console.log( data ); // Data returned
      console.log( textStatus ); // Success
      console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
      console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
}
else {
  // do whatever
}
```

Edit: If you do it this way you would want to make sure to clear out the variable by using `sessionStorage.removeItem("loggedInStatus");` on logout.